# Set Map Language with Bing Maps JavaScript V8 API

Tags: bing-maps

In Bing Maps V7 there was an [mkt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427600.aspx) param to set the language of the map. This [is gone in V8](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34563.bing-maps-v7-to-v8-migration-guide.aspx#What_s_New_in_Bing_Maps_V8) and instead the browsers default language is used:

> The Bing Maps v8 web control no longer requires the use of a mkt
>   parameter to localize the map. If one is not provided the map will
>   automatically attempt to set the language of the map based on the
>   user’s browser settings and/or location.

But we need to set the language according to the website's user setting (which can be different from the browser language). Is there a way to set this using the Bing Maps V8 JavaScript API?

Comment: There is no supported way to override the map culture settings yet. We are looking at making this an option, however, we have found that the only time this is needed is when testing. The user setting detections are very good and in most cases would likely align with the setting the user would select on your webpage.

Answer (score 2):

In Bing v8 we can use **setLang** and **setMkt** parameters to override the default localization setting.

please find below example for setting localization parameters:

```
<script type='text/javascript' 
src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&setMkt=en-IN&setLang=en' 
async defer>
</script>
```

Please find the below link from where I found this information :
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712553.aspx#Localizing the Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712553.aspx#Localizing%20the%20Map)